# value cannot be resolved error in java

Tags: java, string, scope

I am getting the error "value cannot be resolved" when i do the string check with the password field. Can anyone tell what is wrong with my code. It shows the error where I have declared my string variable "pass". My code is as below

```
public class PassWord implements ActionListener {
    JButton b;
    PassWord() {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Home"); 
        JPasswordField passwd = new JPasswordField();
        JLabel l1=new JLabel("Enter Password");  
        l1.setBounds(625,310, 150,30); 
        passwd.setBounds(600,340,150,30);
         b = new JButton("Login");
         b.setBounds(640,380,70,30);
         b.addActionListener(this); 


         f.add(passwd); f.add(l1); f.add(b);
         f.setSize(1280,720);
         f.setLayout(null);    
             f.setVisible(true);          
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        String pass =  passwd.getPassword();
        if(pass.equals("test")) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: There's no variable called `passwd` in that method.  Did you mean to make that a class-level variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems in your code.

First you have to make your `JPasswordField` to a class variable:
Second:  `passwd.getPassword()` returns a character array, not a string:

```
public class PassWord  implements ActionListener {
    JButton b;
    JPasswordField passwd;
    PassWord() {
        JFrame f=new JFrame("Home"); 
        passwd = new JPasswordField();
        JLabel l1=new JLabel("Enter Password");  
        l1.setBounds(625,310, 150,30); 
        passwd.setBounds(600,340,150,30);
         b = new JButton("Login");
         b.setBounds(640,380,70,30);
         b.addActionListener(this); 


         f.add(passwd); f.add(l1); f.add(b);
         f.setSize(1280,720);
         f.setLayout(null);    
             f.setVisible(true);          
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {    
        char[] pass =  passwd.getPassword();
        if("test".equals(String.valueOf(pass))) {
        System.out.println("Success");
        }
     }

}
```

Comment: Thanks it works :)

Answer (score 2):

The error you get:

> passwd cannot be resolved

is caused because you need to declare **JPasswordField passwd**   as a class member, you declared it in the constructor only and therefore is not visible in the method **actionPerformed**